# .htaccess mod_rewrite with 3 directories levels

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I manage 3 subdirectories levels on Htaccess?
Explanation:

- `http://example.com/category1/`
- `http://example.com/category2/`
- `http://example.com/category3/`

`RewriteRule  to *category.php?category=$1*`

- `http://example.com/category1/type1/`
- `http://example.com/category2/type7/`
- `http://example.com/category3/type8/`

`RewriteRule to *type.php?category=$1&type=$2*`

- `http://example.com/category1/type1/company3/`
- `http://example.com/category2/type7/company4/`
- `http://example.com/category3/type8/company9/`

`RewriteRule to *company.php?category=$1&type=$2&company=$3*`

.htaccess file is located in initial root folder (where index.php)

Is the next the best way?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(?:/)?$ /category.php?category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(?:/)?$ /type.php?category=$1&type=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)(?:/.*)?$ /company.php?category=$1&type=$2&company=$3 [L]
```

Comment: If pre-splitting the path onto multiple parameters is the goal, then yes; that's the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fairly close. Just note that `RewriteCond` is applicable to next immediate `RewriteRule` only so you check of `!-f` will only be used for first rule. You can have a separate rule to discard all requests that are for existing files and directories.

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ type.php?category=$1&type=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ company.php?category=$1&type=$2&company=$3 [L,QSA]
```